# How I can send post request without response python3

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, post, python-requests, python-multithreading

I use requests lib python 3.8.I have a list that contain 20 urls.I create a thread for each one. inside thread I have ( while True ) send post request to an address ,sometime address is busy and response time become high .
How I can send post request  immediately . I don't need response data

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple socket for this, something like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(f"POST /{URL} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {HOST}\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: {LENGTH}\r\n\r\n{CONTENT}")
```

Or as variant, use timeout (its size is variable) of requests lib:

```
try:
    requests.post(f"http://{HOST}:{PORT}/{URL}/",timeout=0.1)
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: 
    pass
```

Comment: my site is https. is different ?

Comment: The first method will not work but the second will do

Comment: When we consider, for example, the timeout equal to one second, if the package does not reach the destination within this one second, the package will be removed from the network or not, only a new request will be sent.